# Relationship between two tables laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.1

How to make a relationship between two tables. i have two tables `state` and `members`

in state table i have id , name and in members table i have `id , state_id, members_name` etc.

i need to fetch all data from table like his/her `name,state name` etc

State.php

```
class State extends Model {
   protected $table="state";

    protected $fillable = 
        [
            'name'
    ];

 public function member()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Members');
}

}
```

Members.php

```
class Members extends Model {


    protected $table="members";
    protected $fillable = 
    [
            'members_name',
            'state_id'
   ];


  public function state(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\State');
}


}
```

view:

```
@foreach($users as $user)

   {{$user->name}}//i have not got district name
@endforeach
```

How to get state name? Is there wrong in using relation.please help me

Answer (score 3):

There are many ways and it really depends on what do you need. For example, in a controller:

```
$members = State::all()->members()
```

In a view:

```
@foreach($members as $member)
   {{ $member->name }}
@endforeach
```

You can learn more about One-To-Many relationship in the official [Eloquent One-To-Many doc](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many).

Comment: - can you help me to make relationship in this case

Comment: What exactly do you mean? Your relations look fine.

Comment: but i have not got state name in view - {{$user->name}}

Comment: my controller :$users = Member::find($id);  return view('results',compact('members'));

Comment: @RanjeetKarki, can you choose my answer as best answer please?

Answer (score 1):

I believe it should be done this way:

```
@foreach($users as $user)

    {{$user->state->name}}

@endforeach
```